# Dagger 2 Build IllegalArgumentException compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception, dagger-2

I have been testing out Dagger 2, and everything had been working, until I did a bit of refactoring. Now gradle is throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`, and I cannot figure out what I changed that is now causing the error. I haven't made any changes to the gradle file, and this seems to be the brunt of the stack trace:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':mobile:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    ...

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:108)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writer.ClassName.peerNamed(ClassName.java:130)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.SourceFiles.membersInjectorNameForMembersInjectionBinding(SourceFiles.java:266)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.InjectBindingRegistry.registerBinding(InjectBindingRegistry.java:194)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.InjectBindingRegistry.registerBinding(InjectBindingRegistry.java:171)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.InjectProcessingStep.process(InjectProcessingStep.java:129)
    at dagger.shaded.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:228)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    ... 89 more
```

No files are being generated by Dagger as well, and they were previously. I have been trying every method to fix this that I can find, mostly involving fixing the gradle files or clearing out the build folder, but so far nothing has worked.

---

Quick update (since I noticed a few up-votes); I never did find out what I did wrong, I ended up reverting to an old build. After the revert, I did the refactoring again and it worked fine. I must've done something different when I initially refactored the code, but I have no idea what it was.

If anyone has an idea of what could have caused this, I'm sure it will help out anyone else who has, or will in the future, run into this issue.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this issue while bringing Firebase into the project.  It was the first background service being added to the project so I decided to do some sleuthing with a service that did nothing.

This built:

```
public class HopefullyBuildsService extends IntentService {
    public HopefullyBuildsService(String name) {
         super(name);
    }

     @Override
     protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

     }
}

..............

@ApplicationScoped
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class, RestModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    ...
    void inject(HopefullyBuildsService service);
    ...
}
```

But this caused the build to fail:

```
public class HopefullyBuildsService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
}

..............

@ApplicationScoped
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class, RestModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    ...
    void inject(HopefullyBuildsService service);
    ...
}
```

For whatever reason trying to inject directly into a Firebase derived service causes the build to fail in the way you described. However indirectly injecting into another class and then instantiating it the old-fashioned way inside the service allowed it to build again.

```
public class FirebaseDaggerInjectHelper {

    @Inject
    PersistManager persistManager;

    @Inject
    RestClient restClient;

    @Inject
    OtherClasses stuffEtc;

    public FirebaseDaggerInjectHelper(MyApplication application){
        application.getApplicationComponent().inject(this);
   }

    //getters and setters n stuff
}

........

@ApplicationScoped
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class, RestModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    ...
    void inject(FirebaseDaggerInjectHelper helper);
    ...
}

........

public class HopefullyBuildsService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private FirebaseDaggerInjectHelper injectHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        injectHelper = new FirebaseDaggerInjectHelper((MyApplication) getApplicationContext());
}
```

And then it built fine.  Admittedly, having this middleman class is annoying and the firebase derived service has to interact with the injected components in an indirect fashion. But its not clear to me why I cannot inject into a Firebase derived service, Or what is special about Firebase that made Dagger2 unhappy.

Comment: +1 for your workaround, it was exactly my issue also with FirebaseMessagingService after I tried to inject dependencies into it. Maybe there's some issue with obfuscation?

Comment: How I wish this could have been explained by Firebase and Dagger guys

Comment: Happens when you extend "FirebaseInstanceIdService" as well.

Comment: Unbelievable this is the cause of it. Is there an issue report for this to google of square already?

Comment: It seems that this bug has been fixed; my app used to require this hack, but with play services 11.8.0 it's no longer needed

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet solved in dependency `dagger2.0` still throws `IllegalArgumentException`, I agree with @KATHYxx's approach to solve it in `dagger2.0`
But [square](https://github.com/google/dagger) has solved the `inject` in `dagger2.7` version. 
So, updating the dependency fixed the issue

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7"
apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7"
```