# Does firebase manage user data like device token, bundle id etc at their own when sending push notifications or we have to manage these data?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was previously using parse for sending push notifications but now we are required to switch to other service provider. I am thinking of using firebase as my only requirement is sending push notifications on IOS and Android, and firebase seems to  be close to what my requirements are.

I was searching for any facility provided by firebase to manage the user's data as in their device ids against the bundles they are entitled to. So, When i have to broadcast notifications, will firebase be retrieving appropriate bundles based on userid (or something like that) and vice versa (as parse was doing)? or do i need to manage this data and pick up appropriate device id before sending notifications?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

All you really need on your server is your server API key and an appropriate InstanceID (generated by each device to address it individually). You -do- need to store the InstanceID if you want to tailor notifications to specific devices but there is also a mechanism to send segment and topic notifications that does not require you to store individual InstanceIDs.

For FCM you just make a HTTP POST request to their API endpoint, supplying your Server API key in the Authorization Header, and the InstanceID (Token); notification title; notification text; and any additional parameters in the request body.

Easy enough to test with [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) or [FireBase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) and they also have Node.js and Java [libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup) you can use on your server. It's [backwards compatible with GCM and Amazon SNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38300450/fcm-with-aws-sns/38623482#answer-38626398) so you can use that too should you wish.

For Android you just make a few small [updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) to your gradle build configuration, include the google-services.json file you download from google for your app/s and [extend a few classes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-device) like `FirebaseInstanceIdService` and `FirebaseMessagingService`.

*Note: If you're using Dagger2 for Dependency Injection on Android there is a small incompatibility that is easily fixed by following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629856/dagger-2-build-illegalargumentexception-compiledebugjavawithjavac/38108182#38108182).*

Comment: Thanks Nathan.. My question was who has to manage the registartion_ids? Lets say i have 1000 users and if i need to send notification to Tom, am i needed to retreived the registation id or firebase would be able to do that if i provide userid=Tom (or something simillar) ?

Comment: In short you have to manage the relationship between users and their device tokens. Things like topics and device groups do make this a simple process.

Comment: You should send the InstanceID (Token) to your server every time it changes. (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-device#access_the_registration_token)

The easiest way I've found to do this is to save the token locally in shared preferences on update (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454501/firebase-fcm-force-ontokenrefresh-to-be-called) and set an additional TokenChanged flag in SharedPreferences.

Your app can check this flag on launch and persist the InstanceID to your API (with something like Retrofit) as appropriate.